# How can I calculate $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-e^x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have no idea to start this.

Any hint or solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make substitution $e^{x}=u$ and get [exponential integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-e%5Ex%29+from+0+to+infinity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is that you (probably) can't do this without using the exponential integral (a function):

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x) = -\int_{-x}^\infty {e^{-t}\over t}dt$$

With that function you could solve it if you do the substitution $u=e^x$.